# Flask to HTML variables

Tags: python, html, flask, web

my code in flask

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_index():   
    #label = 'cracked'
    return render_template('index.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Debug/Development
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port="5000")
```

my code in html:

```
<html>

  <body>
 <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img_to_display.jpg')}}" alt={{name}}/>
 <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>">  
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```

I want to have name,lat and lng as variables in my html code that i can controle from my python code(Flask).. any help. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Pass the values into the `render_template` function.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_index():   
    #label = 'cracked'
    lat = 0
    lng = 0
    return render_template('index.html', lat=lat, lng=lng)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Debug/Development
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port="5000")
```

Then you can access them in the template.

```
<html>

  <body>
 <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img_to_display.jpg')}}" alt={{name}}/>
 <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q={{ lat }},{{ lng }}">  
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```